# Best way to transform string [text][text][text][text][text] to XML?

Tags: c#, xml

I have a string in the format of  [text][text][text][text][text] and I want to transform it to XML syntax. My code below does this but I wonder if/how I can improve it, would you do it in a different way?

```
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\values.txt");
    string message = tr.ReadToEnd().Trim().Replace("][", "|").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
    tr.Close();            
    string[] nodeStart = { "<firstNode>", "<secondNode>", "<thirdNode>", "<fourthNode>", "<fifthNode>" };
    string[] nodeEnd = { "</firstNode>", "</secondNode>", "</thirdNode>", "</fourthNode>", "</fifthNode>" };
    string[] messageArr = message.Split('|');

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("<rootNode>");
    for(int i = 0; i < messageArr.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", nodeStart[i], messageArr[i], nodeEnd[i]));
    }
    sb.AppendLine("</rootNode>");
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

The output/format of the xml is simplified for this example
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `System.Xml.XmlWriter` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx

Comment: I'm confused, why do you need to name each node differently within your rootNode if they are the same sort of item?

Comment: sorry it's not the same sort of item, [text] could be first name last name, city, country or whatever

Comment: I never say never, but really, *never* hand code XML, not ever. There are **many** correct ways to do this under the System.Xml namespace, including `XmlWriter` & `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`. Please, don't do this e.g. What happens if the data contains an `&` character, or any one of many other special XML characters?

Comment: thanks, comments like this is what I was after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support my comment:
Use `System.Xml.XmlWriter`

Here is an article with example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx

Alternatively use `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` and `XDocument.Save()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ (with a dependency on .NET 4 or Silverlight 4 because of [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28VS.100%29.aspx)):

```
string[] elementNames = new string[] { "first", "second", "third", "forth", "fifth" };
string input = "[text][text][text][text][text]";

XElement[] elements = input
     .Substring(1, input.Length - 1)
     .Split("][")
     .Zip(elementNames, (value, element) => new XElement(element, value))
     .ToArray();

XDocument document = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Root", elements)
);

string xml = document.ToString();
```